# My OnFormSubmit trigger needs to complete before add-on's OnFormSubmit trigger fires

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, add-on

I'm using the Form Publisher add-on with Google Forms in order to turn each Forms response into a Google Doc. It's a great add-on.

I've written my own OnFormSubmit trigger (Head deployment; part of an app-script library) that renames the file(s) the form user may have uploaded as part of their form response. (The filenames are only available from the Drive.App file object, *not* from the form response itself.)

Based on the upload filenames that Form Publisher puts into the Google doc it generates, I can tell that sometimes the doc is being generated BEFORE my OnFormSubmit renames the files, and sometimes it is being generated AFTER my OnFormSubmit fires.

So my question is this: Given that I have no real knowledge of how Form Publisher works (though I would think OnFormSubmit would be at the heart of it), is there any way that I can assure that my OnFormSubmit will fire and finish before Form Publisher begins to generate the Google Doc?

Comment: I'm afraid that if you have two triggers that fire from the same event there is no way to ensure one starts/finishes before the other. They go off to the server asynchronously so the order will never be dependable. The way you normally deal with this is to make them part of the same trigger, but since you are mixing and matching your own script with closed source add-on script, that is not possible. If you wanted your one to fire _after_ then you could just use a delay, but to make it fire before, you will probably be best off writing your own script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, iansedano! I've continued to test and research, and everything I've seen points to your comment being correct.

> I'm afraid that if you have two triggers that fire from the same event there is no way to ensure one starts/finishes before the other. They go off to the server asynchronously so the order will never be dependable. The way you normally deal with this is to make them part of the same trigger, but since you are mixing and matching your own script with closed source add-on script, that is not possible. If you wanted your one to fire after then you could just use a delay, but to make it fire before, you will probably be best off writing your own script.

For the record, there appears to be one small glimmer of hope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287664/can-i-use-scripts-alongside-or-in-reference-to-an-add-ons-functions-in-google-s). I read that post's answer as saying that an add-on could use `@customfunction` to expose a function that my OnFormSubmit trigger could call; that custom function could then, for example, put the add-on to sleep for a bit (or even better: sleep until I call a second custom function to signal that I'm done) in order for my OnFormSubmit trigger to go first.

But other than that possibility, I've come up with nothing.